# Screen scroll issue in ionic1

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

When I focus on any of the field, Keyboard is opening but the screen is not scrolling to the specific field until I write anything. Please see link. I'm facing this issue in Android, in iOS everything is working fine.

Screen is also not getting reset when keyboard closes.

config.xml:

`<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
    <preference name="Fullscreen" value="false" />
    <preference name="KeyboardShrinksView" value="true" />
    <preference name="android-windowSoftInputMode" value="adjustResize|stateHidden" />`

template.html :

```
<ion-view cache-view="false" class="register-bg">
    <ion-scroll has-bouncing="false"></ion-scroll>
</ion-view>
```

Controller.js

```
  Keyboard.shrinkView(false);
```

App.js:

```
$ionicConfigProvider.scrolling.jsScrolling(false);
```

Please see below video for reference : https://www.dropbox.com/s/i6fl8yk8inyai8h/keyboard.mov?dl=0

Comment: do you have multiple input fields or just one in your view.

Comment: @lakshay i have multiple input fields. can you pls see video link i have shared.

Comment: add this line in your controller `cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true); ` and see if this works for your problem

Comment: this is also not working :(

Comment: That was some CSS issue. Removed some classes & it starts working. Anyways thanks